# Select Query depending on list values in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I've a sql table that has these column names: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10. I've also a list in my Asp.Net code (C#).

```
        public static List listColumns = new List();
```

And listColumns contains c1, c2.. c10 randomly. For example it can contains c1, c5, c6, c9. I want to make a query with this conditions. So, If the list has these values, my query should be:

```
SELECT c1, c5, c6, c9 FROM Table
```

The listColumns may contains different values and has different counts. How can I do this query regularly?

Comment: use stringbuilder and loop the list

Comment: You can do it by using string.Join method.

Comment: Most times i see columns like `c1....c100` that actually should be a relation table which is linked to this table via foreign-key. You should refactor your model, this process is called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Then your query will become: `Select value From T2 WHERE t1Id=@ID` or `Select value FROM T2 WHERE t1IDs IN(1,5,6, 9)`

Comment: How are you querying the database?  Through Linq or ADO.NET?  What are you doing with the results - binding something to them?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
List<string> columnNames = new List<string> {"c1", "c2", "c4"};
string result = string.Join(", ", columnNames);

string sql = "SELECT " + result + " FROM Table";
```

Answer (score 0):

It might make more sense, if you only have ten columns, to return them all and select the ones you need in code.

For example, if you're binding something like a `GridView` to your results, you can create bound columns programmatically (disclaimer:  this is from memory):

```
var data = GetData();  // Get all 10 of your columns

var gridView = new GridView() { Id = "gridView1", AutoGenerateColumns = false };
foreach(var colName in listColumns)
{
   gridView.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { DataField = colName });
}
gridView.DataSource = data;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
sSQL = "SELECT [MIS.System.Beneficiaries].[ID] As '  الرقم التسلسلي '" _
                     + FullName + NationalNumber + Gender + YearOfBirth + phone + Email + RelativePhoneNumber + Districts + City + Address + Date1 + Time + AuditName + VistNumber + SupervisorName + Benfishrieshere +
                     "  FROM [MIS.System.Beneficiaries] INNER JOIN [MIS.Lookup.Districts] on [MIS.System.Beneficiaries].DistrictID=[MIS.Lookup.Districts].ID INNER JOIN [MIS.Lookup.Gender] on [MIS.System.Beneficiaries].GenderID=[MIS.Lookup.Gender].ID   LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[MIS.System.Beneficiaries.SpotCheck] on [MIS.System.Beneficiaries].ID =[MIS.System.Beneficiaries.SpotCheck].BenfiiciriesID  WHERE  [dbo].[MIS.System.Beneficiaries.SpotCheck].[Date] > Convert(datetime,'" + textbox6_1.Text + "')  AND [dbo].[MIS.System.Beneficiaries.SpotCheck].[Date] < Convert(datetime,'" + textbox2.Text + "') AND  [dbo].[MIS.System.Beneficiaries.SpotCheck].[CompanyID] ='" + DropDownList4.SelectedValue + "'   "
```

Comment: Could you add some words to describe how your solution solves the problem?